# Generics function in typescript can't find interface property

Tags: angular, generics, typescript

I am trying to create the following function in typescript using generics but it is showing me the following error:

> "Propoerty 'id' does not exist on type 'CustomerInterface'"
>   This happens in: customer.id === +id

```
        getCustomer<CustomerInterface>(id: number | string){
            return this.getCustomers<CustomerInterface>('')
                .then(customers => customers.find(customer => customer.id === +id));
        }
```

The interface definition:

```
export interface CustomerInterface {
    id: number
    name: string
    display_name: string
    address: string
    city: string
    phone_number: string
}
```

Comment: can u add screenshot of the error along with the causing line. Also what is your **customer** object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time later I found the solution using Generics constraints  =P 
It should be like:

```
getCustomer<T extends CustomerInterface>(id: number | string){
    return this.getCustomersCloseTo<T>('')
        .then(customers => customers.find(customer => customer.id === +id));
}
```